# How do I convert list into dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have this. 
`[{"what": "Drink", "allDay": true, "id": 12, "when": "2020-05-13", "end": "2020-05-13"}]`
I'm trying to print the value of "what", but I'm having trouble converting this list into dictionary. I simply need the brackets come off. How do I do this? Thank you. :)

Comment: `d = l[0]`. There you go, `d` is now a dict.

Comment: This is a list with a dictionary in it. Just access the first element of the list to get to the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of dict(s). So, you could do it as follows.

- If `values` is the name of list variable, then `values[i]` gives you access to a dictionary stored at index `i`.
- The `dict.get(key, None)` will either return a value or None when the key does not exist. This may allow you to avoid unwanted error when a certain field is absent.

```py
# Use of dict.get(key, "value-when-no-match")
# is safer than directly calling dict[key]
# BUT, this depends on your design/logic/requirements.
values[0].get('what', None)
```

### An Observation

Since `"allDay": true` was in your sample data, I assume that most likely you are trying to read this from a **JSON** file. If that is the case, and if you are using `json` library in python, that could be easily dealt with using `json.load(), json.loads()`.

### Dummy Data

Note that you had a boolean value (for `"allDay"`) as `true` >> Python expects `True` with a **capital T**.

```py
values = [
    {
        "what": "Drink", 
        "allDay": True, 
        "id": 12, 
        "when": "2020-05-13", 
        "end": "2020-05-13"
    },

    {
        "what": "Eat", 
        "allDay": True, 
        "id": 14, 
        "when": "2020-05-14", 
        "end": "2020-05-14"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I get this error saying, 'str' object has no attribute 'get'. What is the problem?

Comment: *"is safer than directly calling ..."* — That really depends on what the code is supposed to do. If the value *must* exist and it's an error if it doesn't, then `[key]` is a lot "safer" since it terminates in an error instead of silently continuing. Either way, the second `None` argument to `get` is superfluous.

Comment: @RyanOh if you're getting that error, that means `values[0]` (where `values` is the `list` containing the `dict`s as shown in your question) is returning a `str` rather than a `dict`, which means the sample data you provided is not accurate

Comment: @awarrier99 Oh then the value returned is actually string which looks like dictionary. I may have to check on that. Thanks though :)

Comment: So I realized that the value returned was a string dictionary. So I used ```json.loads()``` in order to convert it into a dictionary. Then I did as @CypherX said and it totally worked. Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: @deceze I agree with you on it being conditional to the design/requirements/logic. And added a statement to reflect upon this.

Answer (score 1):

```py
li = [{"what": "Drink", "allDay": True, "id": 12, "when": "2020-05-13", "end": "2020-05-13"}]

di = dict(li[0])

di['when']
```

Comment: The `dict()` is entirely superfluous…

Answer (score 1):

Extract the dictionary from the list:

```
lst = [{"what": "Drink", "allDay": True, "id": 12, "when": "2020-05-13", "end": "2020-05-13"}]
dct = lst[0]
print(dct['what'])
```

Answer (score 1):

What you got is a dictionary inside a list. So your dict is the first element of the list:

```
your_desired_dict = data[0]
print(your_desired_dict['what'])
```

or directly:

```
print(data[0]['what'])
```